# Go Buffalo test with sqlite error: could not find connection named test

Tags: go, buffalo

Buffalo test error on a new project I created with this command.

```bash
buffalo new coke --db-type sqlite3
buffalo test
```

Here is the error:

```bash
[POP] 2023/02/23 13:43:02 warn - unable to load connection development: could not create new connection: sqlite3 support was not compiled into the binary
[POP] 2023/02/23 13:43:02 warn - unable to load connection test: could not create new connection: sqlite3 support was not compiled into the binary
[POP] 2023/02/23 13:43:02 warn - unable to load connection production: could not create new connection: sqlite3 support was not compiled into the binary
Usage:
  buffalo test [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for test

ERRO[0000] Error: could not find connection named test
```

Was there something I miss before running the test on this project? Somebody please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd line of your output,

```
[POP] 2023/02/23 13:43:02 warn - <...>: sqlite3 support was not compiled into the binary
```

As you can see here, the root cause is that your `buffalo` binary was not compiled to support SQLite3. How did you install it? If you used `go install`, you should use `-tags sqlite` option so the command like should be

```
go install -tags sqlite github.com/gobuffalo/cli/cmd/buffalo@latest
```

See the document for more installation options.

https://gobuffalo.io/documentation/getting_started/installation/#custom-installation-with-sqlite3-support

Comment: Yes it was the buffalo binary issue, tried to re-install with -tags sqlite and it worked. Thanks for helping.